# How do I print the second method at the end of the user input? In java

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

1.The program works but it prints out the second method everytime after the user inputs, I don't want this and I don't understand how to change it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import scanner so user can input

class arrays
{

public static void main(String[] param)
{
    String[] animals = arrays(); // creating string array to store information
    forloop(animals);// passing the array to the method forloop
    System.exit(0);
} //end main method

public static String[] arrays() //array method 
{
    String[] animals = new String[5]; //array to store 5 animals

    animals[0] = "Komodo Dragon"; //animals stored
    animals[1] = "Manatee";
    animals[2] = "Kakapo";
    animals[3] = "Florida Panther";
    animals[4] = "White Rhino";

    return animals;

}

public static void forloop(String[] animals) // here the array has been passed as an argument
{                 

     int endangered = 20;
     String answer = "";

    for(int i = 0;i<5; i++) //for loop to print the below 
    //print 5 times using the different animal names.
    {
        System.out.println(animals[i] + ":");
        System.out.println("How many are left in the wild?"); // prints the question
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // allows the user to input
        answer = scanner.nextLine();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(answer);
        if(count<=endangered) // if statement used to print out the smallest number types by the user
        {

            System.out.println("The most endangered animal is the " + animals[i] + "."); // prints out the most endangered animal
            System.out.println("There are only " + answer + " left in the wild.");
        }

        print(animals, answer, i);
    }

}
public static void print(String[]animals, String answer, int i)        
{ 
        System.out.println(answer + ", " + animals[0]);

}

}
```

2.I want the method above to only print after the user has inputted for all 5 questions. I want it to print out in a comma separated list form (Suitable for spreadsheet).
For example:

5000, Komodo Dragon - 5000 being the whatever the user inputs
8000, Manatee
91, Kakapo
100, Florida Panther
18, White Rhino

Comment: You print inside the for loop, so it prints after every question. If you want to save the output to print at the end, consider storing it to a string and printing it all at once.

Comment: Storing what as String? I had the last method as 'public static String print(String[]animals, String answer, int i) ' before but it still printed after every question which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, because at the end of your for loop, you call `print`, which means that it runs at the end of every iteration. You only want to print after the whole for loop has finished. To do this, you have to save the answers somewhere, and then print them all out at the end. Another side note, in your `print` function, you use `animals[0]`, where I'm pretty sure you mean `animals[i]`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense now. Oops, yes I did mean to have 'animals[i]' instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways. Easiest may be to append the input from the user to the String value in array 
For eg. updating respective record with count from user such that:

`animals[0] = "5000, Komodo Dragon";`

This will require extra effort if you want to update the record later. You may use other data structures to 
maintain the record like Maps which may even be simpler. However, one way to do would be two dimensional array such that you can think 
it as of 5 x 2 tables.
Now, array initialization can be of two dimensional such that first column holds animals name and can leave empty for count

```
public static String[][] arrays() //array method 
{
    String[][] animals = new String[5][2]; //array to store 5 animals

    animals[0][0] = "Komodo Dragon"; //animals stored
    animals[1][0] = "Manatee";
    animals[2][0] = "Kakapo";
    animals[3][0] = "Florida Panther";
    animals[4][0] = "White Rhino";

    return animals;

}
```

The `forloop` method now has to update second column for each animals record so we can update it as follows:

```
public static void forloop(String[][] animals) // here the array has been passed as an argument
{                 

     int endangered = 20;
     String answer = "";
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // allows the user to input

    for(int i = 0;i<5; i++) //for loop to print the below 
    //print 5 times using the different animal names.
    {
        System.out.println(animals[i][0] + ":");
        System.out.println("How many are left in the wild?"); // prints the question
        answer = scanner.nextLine();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(answer);
        animals[i][1] = String.valueOf(count);
        if(count<=endangered) // if statement used to print out the smallest number types by the user
        {

            System.out.println("The most endangered animal is the " + animals[i][0] + "."); // prints out the most endangered animal
            System.out.println("There are only " + answer + " left in the wild.");
        }

    }
    //close the scanner
    scanner.close();

    print(animals);

}
```

In the above method notice that, `animals[i][1] = String.valueOf(count);` updates second column for each row where row is given by `i`. And `scanner` has been taken to above of the `loop` since same instance can be used multiple times. Also, it has 
been closed after the loop ends and the `print` method is taken out of loop and signature of the method is also changed since all we need is in the two dimensional array.
Now, as in general table we stored records in rows and columns so, we can iterate over the array to print our records. Thus, `print` method can be changed as follows:

```
public static void print(String[][]animals){ 
     for (String[] animal: animals)
        System.out.println(animal[1] + ", " + animal[0]);

  }
```

Small change is required in `main` method since the array is now two dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is inside your for loop. Maybe consider changing your `print()` to a `save()` and store each result in an array of answers that you can later print out all at once.
e.g.

`results[i] = answer + ", " + animals[i];`

instead of the `system.out.println` in your print method. At the end, you can loop through that and `System.out.println(results[i]);`